How to mock useQuery and useMutation responses for custom react hook
I have a custom hook, lets say useCustomHook that takes no props. Inside the hook I many useQueries from react apollo library. Then I have some functions that do stuff and finally i return an object with let's say:
{
someList: dataFromQuery,
someBoolean: calculationResult,
anotherList: dataFromAnotherQuery
}

I can't wrap my head around how do I mock these api results and let the hook do it's calculations and return the object.
If I render the hook with renderHook and destruct result from it, the result always returns undefined and default values from the hook. But what If I want to test another component that uses this hook, how do I then tell it to use some X data as response so that this consumer component can get the values  from hook and do it's business?

if i were doing this I would probably look at https://mswjs.io/ to mock the actual responses.
